ImportError: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found while trying to use dlib
Hello I am trying to import the dlib library in python so just the line:
import dlib
but I am getting the following error:
ImportError: /home/sstamnas/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/sstamnas/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
I have used the command
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
to inspect libstdc++.so.6 for specific versions of GNU C++ Standard Library (GLIBCXX) and GLIBCXX_3.4.29 is indeed one of those versions. So I dont really understand what the problem is.
Any help would be much appreciated!
